# Rolling 2 dice in Python and if they are the same number, roll again, and continuing

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, dice

So I need to write a Python program where I need to roll 2 dice and print the sum of the 2 dice. I got this so far:

```
import random
def monopoly():
x = random.randrange(1,7)
y = random.randrange(1,7)
while True:
    if x != y:
        print(x, '+', y, '=', x+y)
        break
```

Now, every time the 2 dice numbers are the same (2 + 2 or 3 + 3 etc.) You can throw again. If 3 times in a row the dice are the same, you need to go to jail. I thought I had to work with a while loop using continue like this:

```
    else:
    if x == y:
        print(x + y)
        continue
#continuation of the code above
```

Now if I do have an outcome where the dice are the same it keeps printing out the sum over and over again until I stop the program myself. But I don't know why.

How do I fix This?, because I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: What you describe is not what your program does.  What did you do to trace the execution before you posted?  For instance, putting `print (x, y)` at the top of your loop body would show a huge clue immediately.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need new random numbers in *each* loop iteration:

```
while True:
    x = random.randrange(1,7)
    y = random.randrange(1,7)
    if x != y:
        print(x, '+', y, '=', x+y)
        break
```

Otherwise, `x` and `y` will never change and so your breaking condition will never hold.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the program continues to loop is because its in a `while` loop.

Because it is always going to be `True`, there no way to break the loop.
This may be odd at first but when you look you will see `x` and `y` are defined outside the loop, they will always be the same.

Therefore it will always be the same in the case they are the same.

You would have to redefine `x` and `y` as different variables in the `else` section, or at the start of the `while` statement in order to generate new values for those two variables otherwise the same value is given each time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a structure you could use to change player turns, between rolls, and then send player to jail for rolling 3 doubles. For the doubles we could use a running count that if it hits 3 will `print('Go to jail')`. This is a general idea, for you to work with

```
from random import choice
from itertools import cycle

die = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
doubles = 0
players = cycle(['player1', 'player2'])
turn = iter(players)
player = next(turn)

while True:
    x, y = choice(die), choice(die)
    if x == y:
        print(f'{player} folled {x + y}, Doubles!')
        print(f'It is {player}\'s turn\n')
        doubles += 1

    else:
        doubles = 0 
        print(f'{player} rolled {x + y}')
        player = next(turn)
        print(f'It is {player}\'s turn\n')

    if doubles == 3:
        print(f'{player} rolled 3 Doubles! Go to jail.\n')
        player = next(turn)
        break
```

> ```
> player1 rolled 3
> It is player2's turn
>
> player2 rolled 3
> It is player1's turn
>
> player1 folled 12, Doubles!
> It is player1's turn
>
> player1 folled 10, Doubles!
> It is player1's turn
>
> player1 folled 2, Doubles!
> It is player1's turn
>
> player1 rolled 3 Doubles! Go to jail.
> ```